# '-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command in android

Tags: android, sdk

I am getting this problem on Console when i am trying to open Android SDK Manager:

```
[2014-12-10 14:39:31 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-12-10 14:39:31 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-12-10 14:39:31 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Issue is fixed with Build Tools 24.0.1 that can be updated through SDK Manager (for those that can start it) or downloaded as installer from http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.0.1-windows.exe

It is bug related to Build Tools 24.0.0

Steps to fix:

- close android studio
- Download Build Tools v 23.0.5 http://goo.gl/v0UPm6
- goto \sdk
- rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup)
- extract this zip to \sdk
- it will make tools folder in \sdk
- restart studio and errors will be gone

https://plus.google.com/107852486976928213243/posts/eASLDXpavAX

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82099

Comment: checking your given link.

Comment: I solved it by downloading Build Tools 23.0.5 zip and replacing 24.0.0 tools folder in my SDK, but I also hacked around with android.bat files and other paths before that, so I cannot tell whether will just replacing tools do the trick.

Comment: yeah i have replaced path and done many things but not worked. Now downloading tools.